# Youutbe api v3 save video to playlist

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am looking for a way to save video to a custom playlist on Youtube. Youtube offers this option in their browser, below the video you can click "save" button and popup will open where user can choose where to save a video. Is there an api equivalent of that?

I am searching their api documents but not sure where to look.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [PlaylistItems: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) by specifying `part=snippet` and request body to:

```json
{
  "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "YOUR_VIDEO_ID"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this work with just api key in javascript or requires oauth?

Comment: OAuth is required "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication"